# How does the Oracle CEP work?

Tags: java, oracle, eda

I have some questions concerning the Oracle CEP. It would be fine if somebody could answer them.

1. What are the differences between sequences and relations?
2. How often each query is executed?
3. What are the cases when we have to convert relation to sequence?
4. How the join statement works? Is it applicable only for relations?
5. According to the documentation table and cache event source are pull event sources. Does it mean that the database table or cache will be queried for each event in the current relation when performing join statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked into oracle CEP tooling, but looking at the questions I have feeling that the basics of CEP might be helpful (excuse me if I am wrong and ignore this post). I suggest (if you have not already) to first understand how CEP engines work. Instead of running queries against the data, the continuous stream of data is evaluated against the static query.

http://www.ebizq.net/topics/cep/features/9313.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that complex event processing systems work in another way that traditional databases - instead of data CEP-systems store queries and run them against the incoming data. I don't quite understand when the relation is created implicitly (for example how many events are used in the incoming stream to perform the query against them), when processor's queries are invoked, why we need to track when relation expires?

Comment: I have not worked on any of the CEP tools but have some theoritical knowledge. I believe the no of events on which the query performs in determined by the time window you specify in the query

Comment: Am I right that for the event stream the time window always exists?

Comment: “windows” over event streams

• Bounded by time or count

• Partitioned based on values

• Processed incrementally or in batches

• Defines a “working set” of events to then apply queries to

from http://tonguc.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/introduction-to-oracle-complex-event-processing.pdf

Comment: Thanks. The link has helped a lot.